# Firebase notification not showing alert or banner and badge app icon in iOS Application

Tags: ios, swift

- I have designed an iOS app with push notification enable in it.
  Notification throw through FCM (just for checking), it will only print in console in foreground mode. But when app is in background mode it will not show any notification.
- I am registered in Apple Developer Program account.
- In this account I have created an app id with push notification enable and certificate (for production).
- Created .p12 and .pem file.
- Also created Provisioning Profile (AdHoc)
- Implemented code as given in Firebase for notification in xcode 8 for iOS 10+.
- Properly generated device token.
  Still not able to get notification. Please help..

Appdelegate code:

```
import UIKit 
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })

            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // [END register_for_notifications]
        FIRApp.configure()

        // [START add_token_refresh_observer]
        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                               name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                               object: nil)
        // [END add_token_refresh_observer]
        return true
    }

    /* [START receive_message]*/
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    /*[END receive_message]
     [START refresh_token] */
    func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }

    /* [END refresh_token]
     / [START connect_to_fcm]*/
    func connectToFcm() {
        // Won't connect since there is no token
        guard FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
            return;
        }

        // Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()

        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }

    /* This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
     If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
     the InstanceID token.*/
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
        // FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)

        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token 1: \(refreshedToken)")
        }
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID in didReceiveRemoteNotification: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print("didReceiveRemoteNotification: \(userInfo)")

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }

    // [END connect_to_fcm]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }



    /* [START connect_on_active]*/
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        connectToFcm()
    }


     /*[END connect_on_active]
     [START disconnect_from_fcm]*/
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        //FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
       // print("Disconnected from FCM.")

        connectToFcm()
          print("connected to FCM in Background.")
    }
    // [END disconnect_from_fcm]
}

extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID in UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID in userNotificationCenter: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}

extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {

    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("applicationReceivedRemoteMessage: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you put the information which is getting in console in foreground mode

Comment: I faced this issue. in my case there was issue in server side. check with you are pointing to production mode on server side and also in ios code. Please make sure u r generated correct production push certificates.

Comment: @AvijitNagare.. Even i still face the same. Is there any restriction for payload from server

Comment: Correct. check they are sending correct payload to APNS. ex. {
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9
    }
}

Comment: @AvijitNagare - Right now I am trying to send notification from Firebase "Notification", just for testing purpose.

Comment: @Uma Madhavi  
Notification in Console
 [AnyHashable("notification"): {
    body = Ashwini;
    e = 1;
},
 AnyHashable("from"): 334307550733, 
AnyHashable("collapse_key"): Appleechnopurple.com.FCMNotification]

Comment: @ashwinitechnopurple. ok, go ahead test for sandbox mode then production. once they are done then ask server team to integrate notification payload or configure server. also in your comment i can't see "aps" and "alert" key please check

Comment: Ok I will check . Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

To receive and show notifications in background mode just make sure you have enable "Push Notifications" in "Capabilities" section.

And to display notifications in foreground mode add alert, badge & sound parameters to your completion block in willPresent method.

*completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])*

```
 // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID in UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.